# Place input tag inline with a specific selectRadio option

Tags: visualforce, controller, selectoption, selectradio

I have a select options tag inside a select radio Tag. I am trying to achieve something in which I will have radio button with its label and then an input box in line. below is my apex code`

```
 <apex:selectRadio value="{!calculatorViewBasedOnFrequency}" layout="pageDirection">
     <apex:selectOptions value="{!calculatorViewBasedOnFrequency.frequencyforDaily}" ></apex:selectOptions>
 </apex:selectRadio>
```

and my class is

```
public List<SelectOption> getFrequencyForDaily(){
    List<SelectOption> options=new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('Every WeekDay','Every WeekDay'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('Every','Every'));
    return options;
}
```

Everything is fine now I want that there be an apex:inputfield in line with the Every option like radiobutton EVERY inputbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping it in an output panel may help:

```
<apex:outPutPanel layout="block">
   <apex:selectRadio value="{!calculatorViewBasedOnFrequency}" layout="pageDirection"/>
   <apex:selectList value="{!CONTROLLERPROPERTY}" size="1" multiselect="false">
       <apex:selectOptions value="{!calculatorViewBasedOnFrequency.frequencyforDaily}" />
   </apex:selectList>

</apex:outPutPanel>
```